# pnotify-rails works but icons not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails.

In my web app I used `pnotify-rails`, its working fine but icons are not visible, instead its showing some unwanted symbols.

how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue, when I checked `pnotify-rails` version.
and than searched for the latest version of `pnotify-rails`,

which is 3.0.0, So updated the gem.

All you need is to update this gem by runnig

```
bundle update pnotify-rails
```

Hopefully, there will be no issue with icons.

Comment: thankyou, now icons are visible.
I was working on this for hours.